# Django: Unsupported lookup 'case_exact' for CharField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is the GET request hitting on my server.

```
 HTTP GET /testPage/?persona_name=Aman&key_name=country&key_label=My+Country&key_value=India&Save=Submit 500
```

With the help of this view i am fetching the values from GET request.

```
def PersonaSave(request):
    persona_name = request.GET.get('persona_name',)
    persona_key = request.GET.get('key_name',)
    persona_key_value = request.GET.get('key_value',)
    persona_key_label = request.GET.get('key_label',)
    persona_submit = request.GET.get('Save',)
    return( persona_name , persona_key , persona_key_label , persona_key_value , persona_submit
```

Now following is the function where i am checking whether object with the given persona name exists or not. If it exists then i am updating the values if it is a new persona then i am making new testPersona object.

```
def TestPageView(request):
    x=PersonaSave(request)
    persona_name = x[0]
    persona_key = x[1]
    persona_key_label=x[2]
    persona_key_value=x[3]
    persona_submit=x[4]
    testPersonaName = TestPersonaName(name=persona_name)
    testPersonaName.save()

    if(persona_name is None and persona_key is None and persona_key_label is None and persona_key_value is None):
        return render(request, 'dashboard/test_page.html')

 # Below is the function for updating testPersona . 

    elif TestPersonaName.objects.filter(name__case_exact=persona_name).exists():
        testpersona = TestPersona.objects.get(name__case_exact=persona_name)
        if testpersona.key == persona_key:
            testpersona.label= persona_key_label
            testpersona.value = persona_key_value
            testpersona.save()




#If persona with new name is detected then saving a new testPersona object.
      testpersona=TestPersona(name=persona_name,key=persona_key,label=persona_key_label,value=persona_key_value)
        testpersona.save()

        return render(request,'dashboard/test_page.html')
```

**Following is the error that i am getting.**

```
    django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'case_exact' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.

Below are TestPersona and TestPersonaName models.

    class TestPersonaName(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class TestPersona(models.Model):
        name = models.ForeignKey('TestPersonaName',null=True)
        key  = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
        label = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
        value = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name + " " + self.key
```

May you please explain me why i am getting this error and how can i remove this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after spending an entire day on this question i am able to know where i was doing mistake.

In TestPersona model, there is a field 'name' which is a foreign key to model TestPersonaName.This means that object of TestPersonaName will be assigned to the 'name' field of TestPersona. So the answer would be :

```
def TestPageView(request):
    x=PersonaSave(request)
    persona_name = x[0]
    persona_key = x[1]
    persona_key_label=x[2]
    persona_key_value=x[3]
    persona_submit=x[4]

    if(persona_name is None and persona_key is None and persona_key_label is None and persona_key_value is None):

    # Since no paramteres are persent in GET request(i.e Nothing is filled in form), then we will simply render the blank form.
        return render(request, 'dashboard/test_page.html')

 #  Below is the function for updating testPersona . 

    elif TestPersonaName.objects.filter(name__iexact=persona_name).exists():
        testPersonaName_obj = TestPersonaName.objects.filter(name__iexact=persona_name) #Fetching an object from TestPersonaName model where name = persona_name
        testpersonaSet = TestPersona.objects.filter(name=testPersonaName_obj) #Passing testPersonaName_obj to 'name' field of TestPersona model because name is foreign key.
        for testpersona in testPersonaSet: #testPersonaSet is a QuerySet
            if testpersona.key == persona_key: #Checking whether persona with given key is already present or not

         # If TestPersona object with given name and give key is already present then we will update the details instead of making a new object.
                testpersona.label= persona_key_label 
                testpersona.value = persona_key_value
                testpersona.save()
                return render(request,'dashboard/test_page.html')    

#If persona with new name is detected then saving new objects of TestPersonaName and TestPersona object.
    testPersonaName = TestPersonaName(name=persona_name)
    testPersonaName.save() 
    testpersona(name=testPersonaName,key=persona_key,label=persona_key_label
                ,value=persona_key_value)
    testpersona.save()
    return render(request,'dashboard/test_page.html')
```

Answer (score 3):

change this line

```
 testpersona = TestPersona.objects.get(name__case_exact=persona_name)
```

to

```
 testpersona = TestPersona.objects.get(name__name__case_exact=persona_name)
```

Comment: I am getting the following error now                                                                     
"Unsupported lookup 'name' for CharField or join on the field not permitted" for the this line of code                                                                                            
                                                                                                                           elif TestPersonaName.objects.filter(name__name__case_exact=persona_name).exists():

Comment: no that will be `TestPersonaName.objects.filter(name__case_exact=persona_name).exists()` dont change this line

Comment: Ok I did as you mentioned but i am getting this same error                                                                                           
                                                                                                           
 Unsupported lookup 'case_exact' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: I am really thankful @Exprator that you are devoting your time to help me out.

Comment: change this line `TestPersonaName.objects.filter(name__case_exact=persona_name).exists()` to `TestPersona.objects.filter(name__case_exact=persona_name).exists()`

Comment: I am getting this error now by doing what you mentioned.Error: Related Field got invalid lookup: case_exact

Comment: sorry `TestPersona.objects.filter(name__name__case_exact=persona_name).exists()` this will be the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184987/discussion-between-ashok-kumar-and-exprator).

Answer (score 2):

You should have **2 underscores** between exact and model field name.

Let's say you are matching field called **persona_name**

```
elif TestPersonaName.objects.filter(persona_name__iexact=persona_name).exists():
    testpersona = TestPersona.objects.get(persona_name__iexact=persona_name)
```

`iexact` match the values regardless of case sensitiveness.